# Getting error about creating folder because of date-time format of IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a asp.net application and I am running remotely an.exe file which locates in windows 2008r2 server. This exe file creates a folder according to date-time format. 
When I host this web application into server, the folders cannot be created because IIS date format is like xx/xx/xx. Because it includes / , folder cannot be created. 
I want to change date format like xx-xx-xx. How can I manage this?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" Culture = "tr-TR"%>
```

this did not work.

Comment: can you post your exe's source code?

Comment: It works in the local computer. The problem is not about .exe . It is about server or .net.

Comment: I changed the date format of server, now it works when I call it in the command prompt. But when I host the web application into server it does not work.

Comment: Thanks Mustafa I solved the problem changing the exe file's source code, thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You can format your datetime using [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx). To get the format you want you would use:

```
myDate.ToString("yy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: I have no date in the .cs code. I am only running exe file with a button.

Comment: Looks like it's getting truncated. Can you append to your original question?

Comment: This code calls exe file which is in the server. That exe file is normally creating a folder naming it call date of exe file. Time format is xx/xx/xx. So it can not create folder because time includes / . I want to remove /. I want time in IIS of server must be in the format of xx-xx-xx .